# How can I point the root domain to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am trying to use the domain I just purchased in Route 53 to point to an application running in Elastic Beanstalk exy.elasticbeanstalk.com

If the domain I purchased is example.com and I want traffic to point to my application in Elastic Beanstalk, How can I achieve this?

So going to example.com launches the exy.elasticbeanstalk.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Route 53,  alias records can be used at the root domain (also known as the zone apex) to refer to an Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

From Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Records:

> Amazon Route 53 alias records provide a Route 53–specific extension to DNS functionality. Alias records let you route traffic to selected AWS resources, such as CloudFront distributions and Amazon S3 buckets. They also let you route traffic from one record in a hosted zone to another record. Unlike a CNAME record, you can create an alias record at the top node of a DNS namespace, also known as the zone apex. For example, if you register the DNS name example.com, the zone apex is example.com. You can't create a CNAME record for example.com, but you can create an alias record for example.com that routes traffic to www.example.com.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

For for more details regarding Alias records and Elastic Beanstalk see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html#rrsets-values-alias-alias-target